# Why is it that when I load this page, the href of an <a> tag is getting called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm working on a project where I'm using an organization's header on my own website. The org's website is built on `ASP.NET`, which I know nothing about.  The part that has been tripping me up is getting the search bar on the header to work. What I've tried is the following (with some things anonymized)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    /* Select the <a> element holding the search icon (usually a magnifying glass) 
       and set it as a variable: */
    var searchIcon = $('#id1');

    /* Set a variable equal to the prefix of the URL request: */
    var urlRequestPrefix = "http://www.orgname.com/search/Results.aspx?k=";

    /* Select the search <input> element and set it as a variable: */
    var searchInput = $('#id2');

    /* Make the <a> tag holding the search icon search for the input when clicked.
       Originally it has href="javascript:someFunction()"
    */
    searchIcon.attr('href', function()
    {
        window.location = urlRequestPrefix + searchInput.val();
    });
});
```

but unfortunately that is, for some reason, executing `window.location = urlRequestPrefix + searchInput.val();` when the page loads. Can someone explain why and perhaps help me fix it?

Answer (score 1):

that code is running when the document loads, to set it to the attribute of searchIcon, do `searchIcon.attr('href', '#').click(function () { window.location = urlRequestPrefix + searchInput.val(); });`

Comment: Can you explain why there's the second parameter '#'?

Comment: attr, when called with two arguments, assigns the second argument to the value of the first one. in this case, it's assigning `#` to be the value of the href attribute. This allows you to have a link that points nowhere, thus enabling you to handle the click however you wish to handle it

Answer (score 0):

Because of following code, it executes the function. Whereas you could have set `href` = some string value.

**What it did** - it just evaluated `href` parameter's value , in your case it is `JS function`, and it was expecting it to be `string`. So while evaluating, it redirected to other page as there is `window.location = ...`.

```
 searchIcon.attr('href', function()
    {
        window.location = urlRequestPrefix + searchInput.val();
    });
```

This should be like following.

`searchIcon.attr('href',  urlRequestPrefix + searchInput.val());`

Assumption:  `<a>`'s id is "id1".

Basically , this sets "href" value of anchor to required location. And on clicking that, ( by end user) it will do `window.location = urlRequestPrefix + searchInput.val();`